# Converting SCORM to PPT

Tags: gratis, windows-10, offline, document-converter

I am creating educational content. The tool of my company can export this as a SCORM file, but nothing else.

Since I don't want to do the work twice, I'd like to convert the SCORM file as PPT.

At the moment, I'm very new to SCORM, so I don't have any particular idea on which features of SCORM need to be supported. Very basic support is sufficient for now.

Requirements:

- Works on Windows (Windows 10+)
- is gratis (Open Source preferred)
- works offline (no upload to the Internet)